# cakePHP3 - pure html login page

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x, adminlte

i'm using cakePHP3 with AdminLTE theme, i want my login page rendered with pure html from .ctp with no additional theme view generated by controller, is there a way to accomplish that? i've already tried $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false) in my action function, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layout to be used for the login page, let's call the layout 'loginLayout'. Below is a sample code based on maiconpinto adminlte plugin. If you are not using the plugin, make sure you indicate the right path for your CSS and script files.

```
<?php use Cake\Core\Configure; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><?php echo Configure::read('Theme.title'); ?></title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min'); ?>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE./plugins/iCheck/all.css'); ?>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.AdminLTE.min'); ?>
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
    folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.skins/skin-'. Configure::read('Theme.skin') .'.min'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->fetch('css'); ?>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">

    <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

<!-- jQuery -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'); ?>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min'); ?>
<!-- iCheck -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js'); ?>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./js/app.min'); ?>

<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>
<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); ?>
<script>

    $(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
    });


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navbar .menu").slimscroll({
            height: "200px",
            alwaysVisible: false,
            size: "3px"
        }).css("width", "100%");

        var a = $('a[href="<?php echo $this->request->webroot . $this->request->url ?>"]');
        if (!a.parent().hasClass('treeview') && !a.parent().parent().hasClass('pagination')) {
            a.parent().addClass('active').parents('.treeview').addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On your .ctp file, indicate the layout to be used

```
<?php
$this->layout = 'loginLayout';
?>

<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

    <form action="../../index2.html" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
      <p>- OR -</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in using
        Facebook</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Sign in using
        Google+</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

    <a href="#">I forgot my password</a><br>
    <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->
```